# Making Box Packaging in Illustrator. Symbol are mirror image problem!

Tags: adobe-illustrator

So i have a rectangular box on illustration. I have added 4/6 sides as symbols.

So for the front i added the correct symbol and it looks fine.

Then i added the same design as the front, on the back. But, it looks mirror image and no matter how i turn it still looks wrong.

How do i fix this?

I just want the image to look correct like the front side. I do not know why it appears mirror on the back of the rectangle. Looking for some advice.

Comment: Can you post an image of what you're working on. It sounds like you just need to Reflect the artwork.

Answer (score 4):

The reason your back side looks like "A mirror image no matter how you rotate it" is because, the back side symbol for a 3D cube using the Illustrator 3D Effect should be **reflected and right side up**. You don't want to rotate it it at all, you want to just reflect it.

The sides need to be rotated, but not the back face.

Here's a simple image to show how the symbols need to be set up.

[image]

Note the 2 is a mirror reflection, 3 is rotated 90° counterclockwise, and 5 is rotated 90° clockwise. In this image the 2 is the back face, 3 the left face, and 5 the right face.

The 6 and 4 *may* need to be rotated depending upon how you want the cube to sit.

[image]

You can apply symbols to faces, then **double-click** the symbol to perform the rotation or reflection on the symbol. The 3D effect should update to show the symbol changes.

Comment: Here is my box image http://i62.tinypic.com/1zmmhe9.png

Comment: Err.. yeah.. reflect the "take anywhere" symbol like I indicated above.

Comment: How do i reflect that particular symbol?

Comment: Double click it in the symbol panel and reflect it.

Comment: SO i double clicked that particular image and it opened up the symbol in a new window. But i see now option for reflect option.. sorry I'm literally new to this!

Comment: Try this: https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/rotating-reflecting-objects.html

Comment: Quick question, how do i view the overall box in 3d? Like move it around instead of opening up the Extrude & BLevel to turn the box?

Comment: You don't. Illustrator's 3D is **not** *real* 3D. It just doesn't work that way.